# Android Replace all Occurrences of a text with a Html.fromHtml span

Tags: java, android, regex, android-layout

I need to display GIF emoticons within my textviews therefore I decided to replace all the occurrences of emoticons with their respective gif image using Html  span. However I need a helping hand with replacing all occurrences of the emoji characters.

For example:

> I had a good day (smile)

should be replaced by

`I had a good day <img src: "path" />`

What I was able to code so far:

```
string regex = " "; //this is where I need help with the regex
String output = comment.getComment().replaceAll(regex, "<img src='PATH' ");
commenttext.setText(Html.fromHtml(output));
```

Comment: Are these custom emoticons or emoji? There are already [a number of emoji libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/33) available for Android should that is what you are after

Comment: @EdGeorge I already have my own emojis mate. GIF ones.. I just want to insert them inline using Html.fromHtml like many other tutorials state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply do this `String regex = "(\(smile\))";`This would replace all the (smile) occurrences. This is quite easy to do. Is this what you are looking for?